# Insert Data to multiple tables inter-related via Primary/Foreign keys in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am attempting to write data into two tables, let's say:

```
Primary_Tbl(Id, Title)
Foreign_Tbl(Id, Primary_Tbl_id, Subtext)
```

I want to insert the data in both of these tables but also want to maintain primary keys and foreign keys relationship. The issue is that I won't have primary keys until data is inserted in `Primary_Tbl` that can be used to insert in `Foreign_Tbl.Primary_Tbl_id`

Is there any clean and neat approach to achieve this in Snowflake?

Answer (score 3):

You can insert into 2 tables at the same time with `insert all`, while using sequences to generate ids:

```sql
create or replace sequence seq_01 start = 1 increment = 1;
create or replace sequence seq_02 start = 1000 increment = 1;

create or replace table table_a (id integer, title string);
create or replace table table_b (id integer, a_id integer, subtext string);

insert all 
into table_a values(id_a, title)
into table_b values(id_b, id_a, subtext)
select seq_01.nextval id_a, seq_02.nextval id_b
  , 'a title' title, 'the subtext' subtext
;

select *
from table_a a
join table_b b
on a.id=b.a_id;
```

[image]

Comment: Nice idea, Felipe. I sometimes see Data Vault architectures where they are using sequences instead of hash-keys. A similar approach of inserting as stated in your answer could also fit there...